# fontello font in ie9 not working?

Tags: css, sass, fontello

I have tried to use fontello font to load image by using 'e806' code., In my css class i add a property called 'content' property with 'e806' code. The css class:before load some asian(chinese) letter. which is ascii value of 'e806', it happens only in IE9. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your font file is loaded.

IE9 use `.eot` font file, so may be you lose this font file.